# How do you increase the number of entries output by git reflog?

Tags: git, git-reflog

I have a branch that I deleted (with -D) but I need it back. I thought the git reflog command would be a good place to look. When I run it I only see 50 actions displayed, and I can't find  any commits from this branch. The branch was deleted a day ago, and I was under the impression that it would not be deleted from the reflog for 30 days.

Is there a way to see more entries in the reflog?

Comment: Can you run `git config --get gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` command to ensure that it has a default value (i.e. 30 days)?

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to answer the specified question. As far as I know `git reflog` outputs all entries.
Anyway, I understand that all you want is to recover the deleted branch.

I suggest you to use `git fsck --unreachable`.
This command outputs all unreachable objects: blobs, trees, commits.
Then you can use `git show` to find the lost commit.

If you are unable to find the lost commit then I have a bad news. It is gone.